# Creating a Rank Column with Repeated Indexes

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I want to output the following table:

```
User   |   Country   |   RANK
------------------------------
  1          US            3
  1          US            3
  1          NZ            2
  1          NZ            2
  1          NZ            2
  1          JP            1
  2          US            2
  2          US            2
  2          US            2
  2          CA            1
```

What I have is the 'User' and 'Country' columns and want to create the RANK column.

I tried to use the function `rank()` like
`rank() over (partition by User, Country order by ct desc)` where ct is just the time of the event since epoch but instead of giving some repeated numbers like 33 222 1, it ranks inside the partition, giving me 12 123 1.

I also tried `row_number()` with no success.

If I use `rank() over (partition by User order by country desc)` it works, but how can I guarantee that it also ranks by ct?

Any clues on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite vague about the schema of your data.  But assuming you have data that looks like this:

```
User  Country  Unix_time(epoch)
1     US       1437888888
1     NZ       1437666666
2     US       1437777777
2     NZ       1435555555
```

I think this will work but I can't test as I don't have hive on my laptop.

```
select c.*, b.rank 
from my_table c
left outer join
(select user
    , country
    , rank() over (partition by user, order by unix_time desc) as rank
    from 
        (select user, country, max(unix_time) as unix_time
        from my_table group by user, country
        ) a
) b
on c.user=b.user and c.country=b.country
;
```

Basically I am selecting the maximum value for the time stamp associated with each user and country.  This can then be ranked and joined to the original dataset.